# Convert XML or delimited data to PostgreSQL record set

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a Pastgres table function that accepts a CLOB containing XML or delimited data and converts it to a database record set, without writing to disk.

In Oracle I can do something like this:

```
with xml_tab as ( select xmltype(
'<employees>
  <employee>
    <empno>7369</empno>
    <ename>SMITH</ename>
    <job>CLERK</job>
    <hiredate>17-DEC-1980</hiredate>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <empno>7499</empno>
    <ename>ALLEN</ename>
    <job>SALESMAN</job>
    <hiredate>20-FEB-1981</hiredate>
  </employee>
</employees>') as xml_data from dual )
SELECT xt.*
FROM   xml_tab x,
       XMLTABLE('/employees/employee'
         PASSING x.xml_data
         COLUMNS 
           "EMPNO"    VARCHAR2(4)  PATH 'empno',
           "ENAME"    VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'ename',
           "JOB"      VARCHAR2(9)  PATH 'job',
           "HIREDATE" VARCHAR2(11) PATH 'hiredate'
         ) xt;
```

I can then create Oracle table function that accepts XML_DATA from the app and converts it to a virtual table that can be manipulated in SQL and joined to other tables in the DB.

Is something similar possible in PostgreSQL?

So far i have tried XPATH but it is not returning a record set.
I also tried COPY for delimited data but it looks like with COPY I must write the data.

I must accept actual data document (not storage location) and convert it to a record set that can be manipulated in SQL: filtered, joined, etc.

Comment: Why aren't you doing this in the client code? What counts against that idea and what do you hope to gain by doing it in the db? You almost certainly *can* do this with xpath and some surrounding code, but ... why?

Comment: Don't want to do SQL joins in the client code for obvious reasons. Looking for alternative to dblink to implement data ship join. Dblink would be too easy for my client DBAs ;).

Comment: Sorry - none of what you are saying makes sense. What has dblink got to do with importing XML?

Comment: In other words I trying to virtualize external data in PG without using dblinks.

Comment: But you mentioned using COPY so you are importing data - which isn't the same thing at all, is it? Sorry - I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: External data can come in either as delimited or as xml. I was considering COPY for the former. 
My thinking is that in order to insert delimited data into a table, COPY must be converting that input into db records.
I was hoping for a way to just return those records without writing. Since that functionality exists in other RDBMS, I was wondering if something similar is available in PG as well.
Does this make more sense now?

Comment: If I have to write semi-structured data - that is not a show stopper, as long as I can retrieve it as a record set.
I cannot maintain a separate temp table for each external set and then manage concurrency.